# PhpMyAdmin shows blank page on nginx ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I have created a server block on nginx to open phpmyadmin, but when i try to access it, it only shows blank page with 500 Internal Server Error. But other server blocks that i have is active and works fine. This is my code for phpmyadmin server block:

```
server {
    listen       500;
    server_name  phpmyadmin.dev;
    root         /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index        index.php;

    # Add your IP to the allow list!
    location / {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

[image]

I use php5.6, nginx/1.10.0 and mysql 14.14.

Did I miss something? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is php-fpm running ? Can you check your logs for nginx and php-fpm ?

Comment: as i mentioned above, the other server blocks is active and works fine. php-fpm, mysql service and nginx running well.

Comment: Well, the 500 error should be logged somewhere with more information. Also, is /usr/share/phpmyadmin in your open_basedir php option ?

Comment: yes of course... I was confused how to solve this issue.

Comment: what does the nginx log say?

Comment: FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: phpmyadmin.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:500"

Answer (score 5):

It's because phpmyadmin can't access to php sessions. Just run

```
 chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session
```

Comment: i confirm this way works perfetch! Love you!

Answer (score 3):

Please try install below and check it might work to resolve the fatal error.

apt-get install php-gettext

Thanks!